# keep first item of the list view fixed and add data from database after that item

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

i tried to search this but was not able to get any proper help.I am trying to keep the first item in the list view fixed and add data from database after that.I am successful in displaying this sort of behavior but problem starts when i use on item click in list view, i dont get correct item i clicked...snippet as follows **copyFetchedData** has the data from database

```
for(int i = 0;i<copyFetchedData.size();i++){


    recentSearchedList.add(i, copyFetchedData.get(i).getName());
    selectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

recentSearchedList.add(0, "My location");

in the above snippet the last line overwrites the position of the added element and puts My Location in first position.Now the snippet for onitemclick as follows.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {



    if (displayList == arg0) {

        if(position == 0){
            editLocation.setText("");
        }
        else{
            String fetchedName = (String) displayList.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name is "+fetchedName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Constants.searchedLocLat = copyFetchedData.get(position).getLat();
            Constants.searchedLocLon = copyFetchedData.get(position).getLon();
            Constants.searchedLocName = copyFetchedData.get(position).getName();            
            editLocation.setText(Constants.searchedLocName);    
        }

    }


}
```

the output i get using this fetches me element of wrong position.I know its because i forcefully add element at position 0 which causes this kind of behavior can someone please tell me right way to do it..

Comment: why dont you use addHeaderView() ?

Comment: If you want only first element to be fixed. You can use list view header for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `addHeaderView()` to do that,

```
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1); //your listview object
        View hvw = findViewById(R.id.listrow);
        //Suppose you have one textview in that Row
        TextView tv = hvw.findViewById(R.id.tv1); // get textview object
        tv.setText("Your first item value"); // set text
        lv.addHeaderView(hvw); // add header view
```

Comment: thnks for your replies.. guys.I solved the problem by simply using(position-1) in onitemclick. :)

Comment: @user1441732 Dont you get error while clicking on the first most item? and while you scroll your first item also get scrolled?